# To what is castable QML WebView to?

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qml

Say we have some

```
WebView {
           id: webView
           objectName: "webView"
...
```

and we sucssfuly can find it with:

```
  QObject *object = w.ui->rootObject();
    QObject *object_webView = object->findChild<QObject*>("webView");
```

But why cant we cast it not to QWebView, not to QGraphicsWebView with line like this:

```
QGraphicsWebView * view = qobject_cast<QGraphicsWebView *>(object_webView);
```

So I wonder how to cast dsefined in qml WebView  to some Qt object that has method like `->page()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the code and found that QML Webview element is actually **QDeclarativeWebView**, which is derived from **QDeclarativeItem**.

**QGraphicsWebView** does not comes into inheratance hierarchy. QGraphicsWebView is private member of QDeclarativeWebView.

for you to have access to QWebPage, I guess you have to create your own custom WebView element  using QDeclarativeItem.

Following code should help to clarify matter.

```
QDeclarativeWebView::QDeclarativeWebView(QDeclarativeItem *parent) : QDeclarativeItem(parent)
{
    init();
}

void QDeclarativeWebView::init()
{
    d = new QDeclarativeWebViewPrivate(this);

...

    d->view = new GraphicsWebView(this);
    d->view->setResizesToContents(true);
    QWebPage* wp = new QDeclarativeWebPage(this);
    setPage(wp);
  ...
}

GraphicsWebView::GraphicsWebView(QDeclarativeWebView* parent)
    : QGraphicsWebView(parent)
    , parent(parent)
    , pressTime(400)
{
}

class WebKitQmlPlugin : public QDeclarativeExtensionPlugin {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    virtual void registerTypes(const char* uri)
    {
        Q_ASSERT(QLatin1String(uri) == QLatin1String("QtWebKit"));
        qmlRegisterType<QDeclarativeWebSettings>();
        qmlRegisterType<QDeclarativeWebView>(uri, 1, 0, "WebView");
    }
};
```

By using following code you can create you custom QML web view element and access webpage.

```
//custom QML web view element
MyDeclarativeWebView::MyDeclarativeWebView(QDeclarativeItem *parent) 
    : QDeclarativeItem(parent)
{
   mGraphicsWebView = new QGraphicsWebView(this);
}

QGraphicsWebView* MyDeclarativeWebView::webView() const {
    return mGraphicsWebView;
}

//register webview  wlement in main.cpp
qmlRegisterType<QmlLabel>("MyWebView", 1, 0, "MyWebView");

//use your old code to access custom webview element
QObject *object = w.ui->rootObject();
QObject *myWebViewObj = object->findChild<QObject*>("webView");
MyDeclarativeWebView * myWebView = qobject_cast<MyDeclarativeWebView *>(myWebViewObj);
QGraphicsWebView* graphivsWebview = myWebView->webView();
```

Comment: and how create such object so that it would be usable from external qml not as main ui element?

Comment: this link should help to put QWidget derived object to  QML, http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-display-qwidget-into-qml.html

Comment: I am stupid((( I do not get how to turn this or even [this ](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-phonon-video-player-from-qml.html) Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: you want to put QGraphicsWebView to QML and also want to acceess QWebPage ?, I suggested to create custom QDeclarativeItem, you can simply make QGraphicsWebView, child of QDeclarativeItem, then you can expose it to QML, and from c++ code you can cast object to your custom class and access webview and webpage.

Comment: @`you want to put QGraphicsWebView to QML and also want to acceess QWebPage` - yes..